# while configuring apache server on ubuntu i got this massage "the apache2 configtest failed" when i tried to restart

Tags: apache2

output of the configtest was:
apache2: syntax error on line 219 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: syntax error on line 12 of /etc/apache2/sites-vboxsf.conf:  without machine  section
action 'configtest' failed

Comment: so you have a bad configuration file on lines 219 and 12 of the files listed. Fix your syntax errors or post your config files for review.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you verify the config file /etc/apache2/sites-vboxsf.conf yourself. Without the content of the file it is quite impossible to provide any sensible response.